# Golang interfaces & casting

Tags: go

I have the following code:

```
   func returnTheMap() map[string][]string{
        myThing := getSomeValue()
    }
```

`getSomeValue()` returns something of type `map[string]interface{}`

but it is *always* internally a `map[string][]string`.

What is the best way to set `myThing` equal to the same thing as `getSomeValue()`, but of type `map[string][]string`?

I can make a new object like so:

```
newMap := make(map[string][]string)

// cardTypeList is of type map[string]interface {}, must convert to map[string][]string
for k, v := range myThing {
    newMap[k] = v.([]string)
}
```

but is there any way to do this in-place, or is there any preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

According to [Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface), you cannot change the type of slice directly.

So it seems that your solution is the preferred way.

Comment: This is correct.  Changing the type of a slice is an O(n) operation, and the Golang developers didn't want an O(n) type conversion to look like other type casts (which are O(1)).  To they enforced that you have to explicitly loop over the contents and individually type-assert, to make it clear in the code that the operation is not constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Is `getSomeValue()` your function? If so, I would change the return type to be `map[string][]string` rather than `map[string][]interface`.

If that is not the case, I would create some helpers to go through and check to make sure the types are set to your needs. I have an example in the playground

https://play.golang.org/p/9OPgXGXADY